# не могу залить проект на github с помощью консоли

Tags: git

взял проект с git (git clone) создал новую ветку, отредактировал, жму git push пишет Evrything up-to-date на сайте git'a смотрю проект пишет что обновлено 20 минут назад, но моих изменений нет(ни в какой из веток), расскажите как нормально пользоваться гитом или хотя бы ссылку скиньте и как залить проект

Comment: Поработаю гуглом: как пользоваться написано здесь https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

...я же думаю, что вы все закомитили перед этим!!!)))
Выглядит это где-то так:

сначала нужная часть изменений подготавливается к коммиту с использованием команды

```
git add %file_path%
```

```
в формате /c/xampp/htdocs/TestToGit/functions.php 
после чего производится коммит командой
```

```
 git commit
```

После того, как были выполнены нужные локальные коммиты, изменения можно загрузить в удаленный репозиторий с помощью команды

```
git push origin master.
```

Comment: Лучше оставить один ответ.